# syntax with arrow function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In a code in TypeScript I saw

```
(() => {
    const abc = 'blabla';
    ...
})();
```

What does this syntax mean exactly ? I know arrow functions is JS - so I understand this:

```
() => {
    const abc = 'blabla';
    ...
});
```

But what is the interest of the rest of parenthesis ?

*PS: The original code is*

```
(() => {
    const title = 'New Document'

    NewDoc.initialize = () => {
        render(
            <App title={title} />,
            document.querySelector('#contnr')
        );
    };

    render(
           <Progr />,  
           document.querySelector('#contnr')
    );

})();
```

Thank you

Comment: in this context, it looks like its simply used as a function (slightly shorter than writing out `function`), which is then called immediately. Given it isn't using a `this` - I think it could just use `function` notation instead.

Comment: This is an IIFE, or an "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"

Comment: It's just an [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) using an arrow function

Comment: The second snippet in your question is invalid syntax since you have one more closing than opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript these functions are called **IIFE** (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression), it's just a definition of a function and invoking it immediately!
What is it good for? many reasons...

But, before we go into the reasons, please note that arrow functions are **not** part of your question, as there's not `this` in your example...

Also not that this question is **not** relevant to TypeScript.

Few on many reasons:

- You get to have a scope (By reacting a function), without polluting the global scope.
- Can can defined a "private" functions that will not be accessible outside of the IIFE
- You are in control on what's going in and out of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be decomposed from

```
(() => {
    const title = 'New Document'

    NewDoc.initialize = () => {
        render(
            <App title={title} />,
            document.querySelector('#contnr')
        );
    };

    render(
           <Progr />,  
           document.querySelector('#contnr')
    );

})();
```

to...

```
const myFunc = () => {
    const title = 'New Document'

    NewDoc.initialize = () => {
        render(
            <App title={title} />,
            document.querySelector('#contnr')
        );
    };

    render(
           <Progr />,  
           document.querySelector('#contnr')
    );
}
(myFunc)();
```

The parenthesis you are seeing is wrapping the lambda (anonymous function) in parenthesis so you can call it.

Comment: The extra set of `()` allows you to immediately call your lambda.
`({... Define Lambda Here...})(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Answer (score -1):

**The trailing `()` call the anonymous function. This is also possible with `function`s.**

Since your code already makes use of ES6 features, a simple block of curly braces can be sufficient. In your example, it restricts the scope of `title` to the curly braces which makes the code more predictable. The `title` constant is not visible before `{` and after `}` (it does not pollute the rest of your file):

```
{
    const title = 'New Document'

    NewDoc.initialize = () => {
        render(
            <App title={title} />,
            document.querySelector('#contnr')
        );
    };

    render(
           <Progr />,  
           document.querySelector('#contnr')
    );

}
```

In the same file, you may now have a second block of curly braces and do something else with a different title, without having to modify the first title:

```
{
    const title = 'Other Document'
    // do something with "title"
}
```

*Hint: Avoid `var` declarations. They are not useful any more with ES6 because `const` and `let` are available, and the scopes of `var` variables do not respect simple curly braces.*